# serializearray() does not take form fields

Tags: php, jquery

I have index.php file which stores a form for user signup. But whenever I try to display data that is stored in the serializeArray it says that it is empty. Here is my code for the html form:

```
<form method="post" id="signupForm">
    <div class="modal fade" id="signupModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="signupModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="signupAlert" role="alert">
                        This is a danger alert—check it out!
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" maxlength="30">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email address" maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Choose a Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" maxlength="30">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my index.js I have a function to take all form fields entered and store them in serializeArray.

```
$("#signupForm").submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray(data);
    console.log(data)
})
```

The array results shows that there are no values. I have tried to console log any string to see if I have correctly linked my index.js file to index.php and it works. There is only problem with getting form fields into the array.

> []length: 0  **proto**: Array(0)

Comment: all of your form elements are missing the `name` attribute: *The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in particular the element cannot be disabled and **must contain a name attribute.*** - https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: I have updates name attribute for fields: username, email, password and confirmPassword. However I still get empty array.

Comment: You also need to remove `data` from `serlializeArray()`, it doesn't take any arguments

Comment: Okay, actually that fixed the problem. Thank you!